# Excel - Multiplier Effect / Loop

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a situation that for every 6 contracts I sign I am able to sign an additional 1. That also means that for every additional 6 contracts I can sign another contract. This of course goes on for ever.

```
 Contract    Additional   Additional(2)    Total
 6           1            0                7
 12          2            0                14 
 18          3            0                21
 24          4            0                28
 30          5            0                35
 36          6            1                43
 ...
```

Is there away of doing generating the total without using VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Total" column is related to the "Contract" column by:

`Total = INT(Contract+(Contract-6)/5)+1`

So the formula to fill down would be `=INT(A2+(A2-6)/5)+1` if your "Contract" column is column `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=7*ROW($ZZ1)+INT((ROW($ZZ1))/6)
```